# Count the number of 1's using the Test Operator MASM Assembly

Tags: assembly, masm

I have a 64 bit variable and want to count the number of 1's and 0's in its binary representation. I don't want to change the value in the variable so I want to use the Test operator in order to count the number of 1's in the variable. My issue is that I am not sure how to handle the 64 bit variable when working with 32 bit registers.

```
.data
aBigVar QWORD ?

.code
mov ecx, 63 ; use as loop counter
mov eax, 0b

Begin:
add eax, 01b;
test aBigVar, eax ; error: instruction operands must be same size
jz LoopToStart
inc dl
loop Start

LoopToStart:
loop Start
```

Comment: I'd just chuck the variable into a register and then repeatedly rotate it through the carry flag. The RCL or RCR instruction would do it. You could load the 32 bits at the offset of your variable and process them, then load the 32 bits at offset+4 and repeat. I find it easier to simply maintain a loop-count and a cumulated count than I find it to maintain both of them and a mask as well.

Answer (score 1):

You should handle the upper and lower half of the value separately since this task is bit counting, in which you can handle each bit separately.

This code show a concept, but I'm not good at MASM and I get link error for this code.

```
.486
.model flat,stdcall

.data
    aBigVar QWORD ?

.code
    mov ecx, 32 ; use as loop counter
    mov eax, 1b
    xor dl, dl ; dl = 0

Begin:
    test DWORD PTR aBigVar, eax
    jz NoInc1
    inc dl
NoInc1:
    test DWORD PTR (aBigVar + 4), eax
    jz NoInc2
    inc dl
NoInc2:
    shl eax, 01b;
    loop Start

Start:

    END
```

Answer (score 0):

X86 has the `bt` instruction that can operate on a bitstring in memory. Your *aBigVar* is such a bitstring with 64 bits.

```
.data
aBigVar QWORD ?

.code
mov ecx, 63
mov ebx, offset aBigVar
mov eax, 0

Begin:
bt  [ebx], ecx
adc eax, 0
dec ecx
jns Begin
```

The number of 1-bits is in EAX.